# Collapse/expand parts of .emacs file with org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I recently learned the basics of emacs' org-mode and couldn't help but imagine applying the collapse/expand concept to parts of a source file. I would like to be able to divide my .emacs file in subparts and only display headers on load, somewhat like the following:

```
; ERC config...

; DIRED config...

; MISC config...
```

Each of these would of course be headers to many lines of codes once expanded, like this:

```
; ERC config
(defun start-irc ()
  (interactive)
  (erc-tls :server "irc.freenode.net" :port 6697 :nick "foo"))

; DIRED config...

; MISC config...
```

So is this possible? How could I accomplish something like this with emacs 24.2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As nice as `org-mode` is, it does require some structure, which I don't believe can be maintained the way you want in your `.emacs` file.

What *does* work well is `folding-mode`.  Check out the information for it on the [wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode), but basically what you do is set up comments around the chunks of code you want to put in a fold, like so:

```
;;{{{ some folder of some kind

(a few lines)
(of lisp)
(this "code" is just filler)

;;}}}


;;{{{ a different folder

(some more elisp code)

;;}}}
```

And when it is folded, it will look like:

```
;;{{{ some folder of some kind...

;;{{{ a different folder...
```

Comment: That worked just like I wanted. Got a bit tricky with the import part but  I figured it out.

Answer (score 7):

[Babel](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel) enables you to achieve exactly this (i.e. managing your init file in org-mode). Specifically, see: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#emacs-initialization

Myself, I make use of `outline-minor-mode` in my init file for vaguely similar purposes. Various things are treated as outline headings, but you can set `outline-regexp` as a file local variable to restrict that behaviour, and then you toggle things open and closed with `outline-toggle-children` (which you would bind to some convenient key). The toggle command works from anywhere in the section, not just on the heading.

I start the headings I want to be collapsed by default with `;;;; *` and end my init file with:

```el
;;; Local Variables:
;;; outline-regexp: ";;;; "
;;; eval:(progn (outline-minor-mode 1) (while (re-search-forward "^;;;; \\* " nil t) (outline-toggle-children)))
;;; End:
```

In your instance you could use:

```el
;;; Local Variables:
;;; outline-regexp: "; "
;;; eval:(progn (outline-minor-mode 1) (hide-body))
;;; End:
```

Pretty similar in effect to Trey's suggestion, although I expect with folding you can trivially nest sections which I'm not accounting for (having no need to do so). I feel the outline approach leaves the file looking slightly cleaner, if that matters to you.

Answer (score 4):

You can also take a look at the new [Outshine](https://github.com/tj64/outshine) package which works together with outline-minor-mode to make it feel more like org-mode. In (e)lisp files outshine interprets sequences of semicolons as headers so all existing code which follows standard conventions for comments becomes foldable without any changes. Many org-mode-like key bindings (like TAB to fold/unfold heading, etc) work too.